# Why after upgrade feathersjs I receive error: MethodNotAllowed

Tags: node.js, mongoose, feathersjs, feathers-hook

I upgraded my feathersjs version from 2.x.x to 3.9.0
Now I have a problem with hooks (after)

this is my query:

```
app.service('duties').patch(id, { $set: { status: 0 }}, {});
```

I have below code in my hook after:

```
var query = { "duties._id": result._id }

hook.app.service('parents').patch(null, { $set: { "duties.$.status": 0 } }, { query });
```

With previously version this was work fine, now I receive an error in console:

```
error: MethodNotAllowed: Can not patch multiple entries
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: https://crow.docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html#multi-updates Covers this

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order to improve out-of-the-box security, creating, removing and modifying multiple entries has been disabled by default and has to be enabled using the `multi` option (and secured explicitly). The migration instructions can be found at [crow.docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html#database-adapters](https://crow.docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html#database-adapters):

```
const service = require('feathers-<database>');

// Allow multi create, patch and remove
service({
  multi: true
});

// Only allow create with an array
service({
  multi: [ 'create' ]
});

// Only allow multi patch and remove (with `id` set to `null`)
service({
  multi: [ 'patch', 'remove' ]
});
```

Keep in mind that when enabling multiple `remove` or `patch` requests the allowed query must be restricted (e.g. based on the authenticated user id), otherwise it could be possible to delete or patch every record in the database.

Comment: Where should this go? Is there a file that already has a set of configurations that I can add {multi:true} to? I tried adding it in the model config section and the service.js file in src/services/my_service, but neither worked. If I'm trying on the chat example, where should I put this?

Comment: It's `options` in the `src/services/<name>/<name>.service.js` file.

Comment: What do you mean by "and secured explicitly"? You mean sanitizing, type-checking, and updating the hooks to process arrays rather than single items? Is there a way to easily convert from a single entry to multiple entry hooks? I don't remember needing to build hooks to process multiple entries before the update. Is it possible to go back to that old functionality, especially for create?

Comment: If it worked in your app before you can just enable it again. The problem was mostly with `remove` and `patch`. If you don't limit the query in a multi remove it can e.g. be possible to remove everything.

Comment: @Daff is this not a Feathers Crow change? i.e. > v4. Only I just hit this when installing v3.3.1 from npm. Am I misunderstanding the link between the npm versions and feathers versions? The Buzzard changelog details v3.3.1 but I can't see mention of this change: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/buzzard/packages/feathers/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: The database adapter versions are not related to the main Feathers version. This is a change that has been made in major versions of the db adapters. More details can be found at https://blog.feathersjs.com/feathers-2019-new-years-news-f478d5f2c8cd

Comment: @Daff can you please hint me on how to restrict a query using a specific field name?

Comment: It has not been easy to come across but I have mimicked this code to get what I wanted. The code is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595255/structure-restricttoowner-restricttoroles-in-feathersjs

Comment: feathers knex still does not have this feature.

Comment: The latest version (v6.0.2) or later does.

Answer (score 4):

It can be corrected/enabled (e.g for patch) here

```
\\ @Src/services/[name]/[name].service.js

.
.
.
module.exports = function(app) {
Const options = {
  Model: createModel(app),
  Paginate: app.get('paginate'),
  multi: ['patch']
};

.
.
.
},
```